# Prove the existence and uniqueness of a global minimum for a quadratic function $q(x)$ with positive definite Hessian

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, positive-definite, hessian-matrix, quadratic-programming

How do I prove the existence and uniqueness of a global minimum for a quadratic function $q(x)$ with positive definite Hessian?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by quadratic function here?

Answer (score 1):

If $q(x)= \frac{1}{2} x^\top A x + b^\top x + c$ then you can "complete the square" to rewrite it as
$$q(x) = \frac{1}{2} (x+A^{-1} b)^\top A (x+A^{-1} b) - \frac{1}{2} b^\top A^{-1} b + c.$$
Note that $A$ is invertible because it is positive definite. Moreover, the first term $(x+A^{-1} b)^\top A (x+A^{-1} b)$ is nonnegative because $A$ is positive definite. So,
$$q(x) \ge -\frac{1}{2} b^\top A^{-1} b + c$$
for all $x$, and equality is clearly attained by the unique minimizer $x=A^{-1} b$.